# pygame load images that change filename

Tags: python, pygame

I have a raspberry pi and a picamera that takes photos and displays them with pygame. I changed the captude code to save the date and time and it works fine.

```
import datetime
import time
date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
     camera.capture("/home/pi/photobooth/"+ date + ".jpg")
```

My question is on the pygame image load function how do I open the last saved image. As more images are saved the file name will change.

```
pygame.init()
     screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1024, 780], pygame.NOFRAME) 
     image  = pygame.image.load('image.jpg')
     screen.blit(image, (0,0)) 
     pygame.display.flip()
```

How would I load the last saved image and then close pygame? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you use ISO-8601 date format - YYYY-MM-DD (which sorts alphabetically), it will be the last file in the directory listing.

Comment: That sounds good. How would I call the last image?

Comment: lespaul_flame: You can get a (unsorted)  list of the files via [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Answer (score 1):

If you use ISO-8601 date format - YYYY-MM-DD (which sorts alphabetically), it will be the last file in the directory listing.

```
import datetime
import time

date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
camera.capture("/home/pi/photobooth/"+ date + ".jpg")
```

And then get a sorted directory listing, so the last file will be the latest:

```
import os.path
import glob

PATH='/home/pi/photobooth/'

# Get a list of image files
file_list = [ f for f in glob.glob( os.path.join( PATH, "*.jpg" ) ) ]
file_list.sort()

new_image = file_list[-1]  # relies on dates sorting alphabetically and temporally

doSomethingWith( new_image )
```